# Logger and Appender in log4j

Tags: log4j

I have configured Logger and Appender as follows.
The problem i am facing is that I am not getting the specified threshold log level in each FileAppender means each FileAppender has output of trace level instead of configured
threshold level for each FileAppender though
consoleAppender is working fine in terms of log level.

```
#Configuring multiple logger and appender
log4j.rootLogger=trace,consoleA,file1A,file2A

log4j.appender.consoleA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleA.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.consoleA.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.consoleA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#File1 Appender
log4j.appender.file1A=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file1A.File=C:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file1A.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file1A.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file1A.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.file1A.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file1A.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#File2 Appender
log4j.appender.file2A=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file2A.File=C:\\loging2.log
log4j.appender.file2A.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file1A.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.file2A.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file2A.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file2A.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of typos in your configuration. Firstly I think the levels should be in CAPS.

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE,consoleA,file1A,file2A
```

Also you have defined file1A threshold twice and did not define the threshold for file2A

```
log4j.appender.file1A.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.file1A.Threshold=DEBUG
```

Comment: Thank you for pinpointing my Typo error. It solved the problem. but if you are talking about the appender should be in CAPS such  consoleA,file1A,file2A, not necessary. Yes Level were in CAPS since start.